# Selenium wedriver: Parallel execution throws 'org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: invalid session id'

Tags: java, multithreading, selenium-webdriver, testng, thread-local

I am trying to execute testcases in parallel. When i try to exceed more than 2 testcases on browsers(chrome or firefox or both) on remote machine(my localhost only), the below exeception is being thrown.

*** Main Base ***:
public class TestBase 
{

```
public ThreadLocal<RemoteWebDriver> tlDriver = new ThreadLocal<RemoteWebDriver>();
public static ExcelTestData dataTable = new ExcelTestData();
public static Properties config = new Properties();
public static FileInputStream fis;
public static RemoteWebDriver driver;
public static BasicFunctions basics = new BasicFunctions(); 
public static ExtentReports extentReport = ExtentReportManager.getInstance();
public static ExtentTest extentTest;
```

}

*** Function libraray ***
public class BasicFunctions extends TestBase
{

public void register()
    {

```
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(ObjectRepositories.xpath_registerLink)));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(ObjectRepositories.xpath_registerLink)).click();
    if(driver.findElement(By.xpath(ObjectRepositories.xpath_registrationTitle)).isDisplayed())
    {           
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(ObjectRepositories.xpath_loginTextbox)).sendKeys(dataTable.getData("RegressionData", "Register_login"));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(ObjectRepositories.xpath_emailTextbox)).sendKeys(dataTable.getData("RegressionData", "Register_email"));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(ObjectRepositories.xpath_reg_passwordTextbox)).sendKeys(dataTable.getData("RegressionData", "Register_password"));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(ObjectRepositories.xpath_reg_conf_passwordTextbox)));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(ObjectRepositories.xpath_reg_conf_passwordTextbox)).sendKeys(dataTable.getData("RegressionData", "Register_confirmPassword"));
        sleep(2000);
        try
        {
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(ObjectRepositories.xpath_reg_submisson)));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(ObjectRepositories.xpath_reg_submisson)).click();
        }
        catch(NoSuchElementException nsee)
        {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(ObjectRepositories.xpath_reg_passwordTextbox)).click();
        }
    }
}
```

public synchronized void driverInititation(String Browser)
    {

```
    System.out.println("Thread name is "+ Thread.currentThread().getName() + " and Thread ID is "+ Thread.currentThread().getId());
    if (ExcelReader.gridExecution.equals("Yes"))
    {
        if (Browser.equalsIgnoreCase("Firefox"))
        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/src/test/resources/Executables/geckodriver.exe");
            DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
            try
            {
                tlDriver.set(new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(config.getProperty("Grid_Url")+":"+config.getProperty("Port_Firefox")+"/wd/hub"),cap));
                driver = tlDriver.get();
            }
            catch(MalformedURLException urlex)
            {
                urlex.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("Other exception");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else if (Browser.equalsIgnoreCase("Chrome"))
        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/src/test/resources/Executables/chromedriver.exe");
            DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
            try
            {
                tlDriver.set(new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(config.getProperty("Grid_Url")+":"+config.getProperty("Port_Chrome")+"/wd/hub"),cap));
                driver = tlDriver.get();
            }
            catch(MalformedURLException urlex)
            {
                urlex.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("Other exception");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(Browser.equalsIgnoreCase("Firefox"))
        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/src/test/resources/Executables/geckodriver.exe");
            driver= new FirefoxDriver();
        }
        else if(Browser.equalsIgnoreCase("Chrome"))
        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/src/test/resources/Executables/chromedriver.exe");
            driver= new ChromeDriver();
        }
    }
    if(driver!=null)
    {
        driver.get(config.getProperty("ApplicationUrl"));
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
        javascript = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    }
}
```

}

*** My testcase ***
public class LoginValidation extends TestBase
{

```
//public WebDriver driver;
@Parameters({"Browser"})
@BeforeTest
public void setupInitiation(String Browser)
{
    Thread.currentThread().setName(this.getClass().getSimpleName());
    basics.driverInititation(Browser);
}

@Test
public void execution()
{
    basics.login();
    basics.logout();
}
```

}

Exception:

org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: invalid session id
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591088 (7b2b2dca23cca0862f674758c9a3933e685c27d5),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z'
System info: host: 'PRABU', ip: '192.168.92.2', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_40'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, acceptSslCerts: false, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 2.42.591088 (7b2b2dca23cca0..., userDataDir: C:\Users\PRABUN~1\AppData\L...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:50326}, handlesAlerts: true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: , unhandledPromptBehavior: , version: 69.0.3497.100, webStorageEnabled: true, webdriver.remote.sessionid: f24126658364be46f247f15b580...}
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//div/a[@href='#/register']}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:80)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:44)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:322)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:424)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:353)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:314)
    at com.servicenow.functionallibraries.BasicFunctions.register(BasicFunctions.java:98)
    at com.servicenow.testcases.RegistrationFormEntry.execution(RegistrationFormEntry.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:580)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:716)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:988)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.access$000(SuiteRunner.java:40)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$SuiteWorker.run(SuiteRunner.java:489)
    at org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadUtil$1.call(ThreadUtil.java:52)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: That `BasicFunctions` class has also a `register` method that fails, but I can't find it in the code you posted.

Comment: i have updated the register method. I feel the issue is not with methods.